# Tangent to the curve which passes through the origin.

Tags: calculus

QUESTION:

(i) Find the equation of the line tangent to the curve y=x^2+15x+36 at the point P where x=a.

(ii) Hence find the equations of any tangents passing through the origin.

[My attempt is attached below in the image]

My problem is that I did not obtain the correct equation in (i) which I believe also led to a completely wrong solution to (ii).

[image]

Comment: I hope that's not an image of John Cena.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83L1h.jpg

Comment: I have voted to close your question as "lacking context," as using a photograph of your work to convey vital information regarding your question makes the question more difficult to search for, and impossible for people who rely on screen-readers to understand.  If you type up your work ([using MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)), it will greatly improve the quality of your question, and I will happily retract my close vote (or help you get the question reopened, should it be closed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=x^2+15x+36\implies y' = 2x+15$$

The slope of tangent at $x=a$ is $m= 2a+15.$

The equation of tangent is then $$ y-a^2-15a-36=(2a+15)(x-a)$$

or  $$ y=(2a+15)(x-a)+a^2+15a+36$$

The second part is a different problem.

You want $y=mx$ to be tangent to  $ y=x^2+15x+36$

That means the equation $$x^2+15x+36=mx$$ needs to have a double root.

That implies $$(15-m)^2 -144=0$$ which gives us $m=27$ or $m=3$